# Search in Redux store if specific string exists in messages array

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to use something like a `contains()` function in redux but apparently it doesn't exist.

```
    case types.FILTER_MESSAGES_BY_CONTENT:
        return {
            ...state,
            messageSearchResults: state.messages.map(message => message.content.contains(action.search))
        };
```

Action:

```
export function filterMessagesByContent(search) {
    return {
        type: types.FILTER_MESSAGES_BY_CONTENT,
        search: search
    };
}
```

Console.log of messages returns me this (one of them):

```
0:
category: "posuere"
comments: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
content: "Quisque id justo sit amet sapien dignissim vestibulum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla dapibus dolor vel est. Donec odio justo, sollicitudin ut, suscipit a, feugiat et, eros."
date: "2018-09-07 08:12:18"
downVotes: 15
id: 2
upVotes: 6
__proto__: Object
```

In this case messages has all messages and in `messageSearchResults` I want to put every message that contains the search query I'm giving.

How would I do this?

Comment: Yes I just double checked. message.content is the content of an array as string in which I want to find the query.

Comment: Do you want to be instead using `includes`? Can you show what message and action.search look like?

Comment: I just added those. And if I use includes it says `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think try this, this should returned the filtered messages

```
messageSearchResults: state.messages.filter(message => message.content.includes(action.search))
```

since

```
"Quisque id justo sit amet".includes("id") // returns true
```

However, I should point out that `includes` would work `query` is container in the `message.content`.

Comment: Yes this works thanks a lot! Any idea on why contains didn't work?

Comment: @SinanSamet No problem, I have also edited my answer to point out that includes would only work when the query is container within the message content.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense. But you mean `contains` I guess.

Answer (score 1):

U can also filter like this and check its include or not.

```
messageSearchResults: state.messages.filter({content}=>content.includes(action.search));
```